# Calculation of Hours between to Dates in Decimal

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have two columns, a start date and an end date.
I want to calculate the duration between those two dates in hours.

Example:
Day 1 8:00 AM
Day 2 9:30 AM

The result should NOT be "1:30", but "1:50" instead.

Can you please help me?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Senfiman is right. Sharepoint uses Excel engine to work with calculated columns. This article describes the logic of calculation in Senfiman's formula:

http://excelsemipro.com/2010/12/calculate-hours-between-two-dates-and-times-in-excel/

Answer (score -1):

I found it online:

=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([End Time])),([End Time]-[Start Time])*24,0)